# cannot change font in uitableviewcell using swift

Tags: xcode, uitableview, fonts, swift, beta

I cannot change the font, and i even tried `func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell!, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!)`. 
I am able to update the textlabels without any issues

This is method to select the font based on the table cell index

```
func fontForDisplayAtIndexPath(indexPath:NSIndexPath) ->UIFont?{
    if(indexPath.section == 0) {

        var ind = indexPath.row
        var names = familyNames as String[]

        var fontFamilyName = names[ind]
       // println(names[ind])

        var fontName = (UIFont.fontNamesForFamilyName(fontFamilyName) as String[])[0]
        println(fontName)

        return  UIFont(name: fontName, size: cellPointSize)

    } else { return nil}

}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell!{

    var cell:UITableViewCell
    var familyNameCellID = "FamilyName"
    var favoritesViewCellID = "Favorites"

    if(indexPath.section == 0)
    {

        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(familyNameCellID, forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
        if(cell == nil) 
        {
            cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: familyNameCellID)
        }
        cell.textLabel.font = fontForDisplayAtIndexPath(indexPath)
        cell.textLabel.text = familyNames[indexPath.row]
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = familyNames[indexPath.row]

    }
    else
    {

        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(favoritesViewCellID, forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

    }
return cell
}
```

Comment: Did you make sure `fontForDisplayAtIndexPath` actually returns something?

Comment: yeah it does...i even tried setting the cell.textLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Verdana", size: 18) as a testdirectly

Comment: Has anyone tried to change the uitableviewcell font in swift successfully? I am using the 6/17 beta 2 release of xcode

Answer (score 0):

The problem disappeared after i restarted xcode several times. My code did work for changing the font. Xcode 6 beta 2 was just a little buggy. I have had many crashes with xcode. including it hanging while compiling displaying "indexing" if there was a build error in the code.